# Best way to use Linux with an AMD computer

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, startup, gpu

### Goal

I have a PC with a good configuration, and I'd like to use it efficiently on Linux for programmation purposes. How can I set it up the best way?
The main problem I have in mind is that my CPU/GPU are both AMD and it seems that their support in terms of drivers is not the greatest.

Configuration

- Motherboard: Asus ROG Strix B650E-F Gaming Wifi
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D
- GPU: Sapphire Pulse AMD Radeon RX 7900 XT
- RAM: 32Go
- Storage: 2To SSD dedicated to Linux
- Dual booting Windows on another 2To SSD

### Issue

I tried already installing Ubuntu (Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish), with the following results:

1. a warning `hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err-19)` was present from the start, not being blocking and initially not troubling me any more than this as it was only shortly displayed on the screen before a fast startup. Also [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463310/hub-8-01-0-config-failed-hub-doesnt-have-any-ports-err-19) describes the same issue, with no resolution
2. my fans were really noisy as if the cpu was overheating, the usage wasn't indicative of any disproportionate amount, so maybe it only was a problem with the fans not adaptating correctly, with a speed too high for what was really needed
3. Firefox was lagging at times, which was surprising to me, as I considered my computer to have specs good enough to handle it, so I installed Chromium (which didn't seem to have the same problems, though I only tested it for a short time)
4. an error `<ubuntu storage>: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks` has appeared on the last startup, which is this time blocking. In [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331344/ubuntu-20-04-stuck-at-dev-nvme0n1p6-clean-xxx-xxx-files-xxx-xxx-blocks-duri), while the problem seems similar, I have installed almost nothing on this fresh Ubuntu, especially when compared with the 2To available.

Have I missed something? Is there an "easy" way to handle AMD parts with Linux? Is there a preferred distribution to use in this case (again, this is for programmation purposes, and I would like to have my GPU available for Machine Learning)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: For 1. Try non-ubuntu/non-ubuntu-based distro

Comment: couple years back, with my Asrock z70-x1/3.1 mobo, when it was newish I had issues with RHEL/CentOS 7 (7.2'ish) where rhel would work but not centos; and sound worked in centos 7.9 but not in rhel 8.x; only thing i can think of to suggest is try rocky 8.8 linux, and rocky 9 linux, and register with Redhat at a developer (free) and also try rhel 8.8 and rhel 9.x.  In regards to chipsets no I don't think there's an easy way to handle this on very new mobo's except for waiting till some linux distro accomodates you.    If anyone can prove otherwise I'd like to hear.

Answer (score 1):

I use nvidia gpgpu's with RHEL 8.8 linux, and always download their `.run` file to be able to install offline their drivers as well as CUDA.  This is a manual process, outside of RHEL which RHEL does not support.  I suspect AMD is the same way.

Looking at AMD @ https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers

Once linux is running download the appropriate driver from AMD, they currently offer RHEL 8.8 & 9.2, Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04, and SLES 15.

And for RHEL (not ubuntu) there is ELREPO - http://elrepo.org/tiki/HomePage

> The ELRepo Project focuses on hardware related packages to enhance your experience with Enterprise Linux. This includes filesystem drivers, graphics drivers, network drivers, sound drivers, webcam and video drivers.

Is there a similar repo for Ubuntu?
If not, you might consider jumping to RHEL 8 linux, to use ELREPO, however I don't know if they will be a solution to your late model mobo chipset problem; that's something I would go to their site/forum for and ask that question and search for people with similar problems.